# Erro ao ler a posição (3) do array Bidimensional: Invalid argument supplied for foreach

Tags: php, array

Como posso ler o conteúdo do `array` `$detail[3]` depois de utilizar o `explode(implode)` ?

Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
$aArray = array(
    "Titulo" => array(
        "Class|SubTitulo" => Array(
            "Detalhe01",
            "Detalhe02",
            "Detalhe03",
            "Atividades" => Array(
                "Atividade01;",
                "Atividade02;",
                "Atividade03;"
            )
        )
    )
);

foreach ($aArray as $title => $aInfo) {
    echo "Titulo: ".$title ."<br>";
    foreach ($aInfo as $subTitle => $aDetail) {
        $subTitle = explode("|", $subTitle);
        echo "-- Class: ".$subTitle[0] ."<br>";
        echo "-- SubTitulo: ".$subTitle[0] ."<br>";

        $detail = explode("|", implode("|", $aDetail));
        echo "----- Detalhe: " . $detail[0] ."<br>";
        echo "----- Detalhe: " . $detail[1] ."<br>";
        echo "----- Detalhe: " . $detail[2] ."<br>";
        foreach ($detail[3] as $activity => $value) { // O Erro da nesta linha
            echo "-- Atividade: ".$activity."<br>";
            echo "----- Valor: ".$value."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Porém está dando erro de argumento invalido

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Amigo, você já pensou em fazer um objeto? arrays assim deixa seu sistema muito lento e com pouco desempenho

Comment: Quando você dá um print_r($aArray); como vem pra ti?

Comment: @AndréBaill usando o print_r o array é exibido normalmente. `Array ( [Titulo] => Array ( [Class|SubTitulo] => Array ( [0] => Detalhe01 [1] => Detalhe02 [2] => Detalhe03 [Atividades] => Array ( [0] => Atividade01; [1] => Atividade02; [2] => Atividade03; ) ) ) )`

Comment: @IsraelZebulon acredito que para o que estou fazendo, objetos iria complicar muito, porém você poderia dar um exemplo de como ficaria ?

Comment: Uma curiosidade, qual é a serventia dessa linha esquisita: `$detail = explode("|", implode("|", $aDetail));`? Se for só para tirar as chaves do array, o PHP já tem função pronta para isso: [`$detail = array_values( $aDetail )`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php). Mas acredito que nem isso seja necessário, com chave => valor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que a chave do seu item não é um índice, substitua:

```
$detail[3]
```

Por isso:

```
$detail["Atividades"]
```

Comment: Obrigado, consegui resolver o problema fazendo da seguinte forma `foreach ($aDetail[Atividades] as $activity => $value)`  porque se eu tentar fazer como você disse o `$detail['Atividades']` ainda da erro por causa do `explode(implode)`

Comment: No meu exemplo não está dando erro.

Answer (score 0):

Para pegar os valores do seu array bidimensional, faça o seguinte:

```
$content = [];

foreach ($aArray as $title => $aInfo) {
$content[]= "Titulo: ".$title;

    if (!empty($aInfo)) {
        foreach ($aInfo as $classAndSubTitle => $aDetail) {
            list($class, $subTitle) = explode("|", $classAndSubTitle);
            $content[]= "-- Class: " . $class;
            $content[]= "-- SubTitulo: " . $subTitle;
            $content[]= "----- Detalhe: " .  str_replace(';','',$aDetail[0]);
            $content[]= "----- Detalhe: " .  str_replace(';','',$aDetail[1]);
            $content[]= "----- Detalhe: " .  str_replace(';','',$aDetail[2]);
            if (!empty($aDetail['Atividades'])) {
                foreach ($aDetail['Atividades'] as $activity => $value) { 
                    $content[]= "-- Atividade: ".str_replace(';','',$activity);
                    $content[]= "----- Valor: ".str_replace(';','',$value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo implode("<br>", $content);
```